# Java JNI Launcher in C++: Works without JavaFX, Core Dump with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, java-native-interface, java-11, javafx-11

I have written a C++ JNI Java Launcher.  It works if I launch a java program that doesn't use JavaFX, but it creates a core dump if I try to launch a JavaFX program with it.  Here's the code:

[Without JavaFX - launch.cpp](https://github.com/JoshuaD84/jni-issue-stack-overflow/blob/nojfx/src/cpp/launch.cpp)

[With JavaFX - launch.ccp](https://github.com/JoshuaD84/jni-issue-stack-overflow/blob/withjfx/src/cpp/launch.cpp)

The core dump only occurs if I use my native launcher. If I run the JavaFX program with the same arguments using `java` at the command line, there's no problem. It runs as expected.

[Here's the content of the hs_err file, in a pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/GMaimEdH)

Rather than paste in code from a handful of files, I created a repository with two branches with complete runnable examples.

[Full Example - No JavaFX](https://github.com/JoshuaD84/jni-issue-stack-overflow/tree/nojfx)

[Full Example - With JavaFX](https://github.com/JoshuaD84/jni-issue-stack-overflow/tree/withjfx)

You can run the examples by editing `build.sh` and `run-native.sh` and changing the line `jdk="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle"` to be accurate for your system. Then:

```
./build.sh          #compiles the java program and cpp program
./run-native.sh     #Sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH and runs the compiled cpp program
   or
./run-with-java.sh  #only on "withjfx" branch, runs via java at cli.
```

As you should see, the `No JavaFX` version runs fine, but the `JavaFX` version only runs via invoking the `java` executable, it core dumps if executed via my native launcher.

Finally, here's the dump I get when I try to run the JavaFX version using the native launcher:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f77513575d8, pid=15281, tid=15301
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0.1+13) (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# j  java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V+6 java.base@11.0.1
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P" (or dumping to /home/joshua/work/javalaunch/core.15281)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/joshua/work/javalaunch/hs_err_pid15281.log
Compiled method (c2)     326  208       4       java.util.Objects::requireNonNull (14 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x00007f7758e10d90,0x00007f7758e10fc8] = 568
 relocation     [0x00007f7758e10f08,0x00007f7758e10f18] = 16
 main code      [0x00007f7758e10f20,0x00007f7758e10f60] = 64
 stub code      [0x00007f7758e10f60,0x00007f7758e10f78] = 24
 metadata       [0x00007f7758e10f78,0x00007f7758e10f80] = 8
 scopes data    [0x00007f7758e10f80,0x00007f7758e10f90] = 16
 scopes pcs     [0x00007f7758e10f90,0x00007f7758e10fc0] = 48
 dependencies   [0x00007f7758e10fc0,0x00007f7758e10fc8] = 8
Could not load hsdis-amd64.so; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
./run-native.sh: line 6: 15281 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./bin/launch
```

On the recommendation of a user here, based on the previous crash, I installed hsdis-amd64.so onto my system and pointed `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at it. I still get a core dump, it looks like all it did was let the core dump load a disassembler:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9e6e2015d8, pid=17530, tid=17550
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0.1+13) (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# j  java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V+6 java.base@11.0.1
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P" (or dumping to /home/joshua/work/so-question/core.17530)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/joshua/work/so-question/hs_err_pid17530.log
Compiled method (c2)     372  187       4       java.util.Objects::requireNonNull (14 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x00007f9e75cbb890,0x00007f9e75cbbac8] = 568
 relocation     [0x00007f9e75cbba08,0x00007f9e75cbba18] = 16
 main code      [0x00007f9e75cbba20,0x00007f9e75cbba60] = 64
 stub code      [0x00007f9e75cbba60,0x00007f9e75cbba78] = 24
 metadata       [0x00007f9e75cbba78,0x00007f9e75cbba80] = 8
 scopes data    [0x00007f9e75cbba80,0x00007f9e75cbba90] = 16
 scopes pcs     [0x00007f9e75cbba90,0x00007f9e75cbbac0] = 48
 dependencies   [0x00007f9e75cbbac0,0x00007f9e75cbbac8] = 8
Loaded disassembler from hsdis-amd64.so
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
./run-native.sh: line 6: 17530 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./bin/launch
```

Update: I've duplicated this issue on both Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 7.

Comment: Is `hsdis-amd64.so` in LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: Related question https://askubuntu.com/questions/710392/java-8-oracle-1-8-0-66-problem-with-printassembly-could-not-load-hsdis-amd64

Comment: It doesn't appear to be. `find / -name "hsdis-amd64.so" 2>/dev/null` gives no results. What is hsdis-amd64.so?

Comment: Have no idea :) but your error message state that "Could not load hsdis-amd64.so". In my second comment it is instruction on how to install it (May be helpful). You can try to debug JavaFX to understand when and why it loads this so.

Comment: I installed it and got it into LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I have edited the result into the original question.

Comment: Guessing it stands for "Hot Spot Disassembler". I don't think that library is the cause of the crash, just a library that the core dumper reaches for.

Comment: Agree. Then you have to dig in core dump. I can't help with that. Not my area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue is in on line 35 with the arguments that are passed the JVM's main method:

`env->CallStaticVoidMethod( cls, main, " ");`

We are passing a c-string to Java where java expect a java.lang.String[].  Once anyone tries to read that argument, the JVM crashes. JavaFX must be reading the arguments at some point between main and start(), and crashing as a result.

The correct line is either

`env->CallStaticVoidMethod( cls, main, "(I)V");` (I haven't tested this one, but it's the common line from the example code provided by the java folks)

or:

```
jclass classString = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
jobjectArray argsToJava = env->NewObjectArray(0, classString, NULL);
env->CallStaticVoidMethod( cls, main, argsToJava );
```